# how to show error with laravel and ajax in views

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a trouble when show error in laravel. I am using **ajax** to send request form from client to server and backward. This is my ajax code and seem to be function `append()` is not working.

```
$('#petition-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  formdata.append('content', tinymce.get('content').getContent());
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    method: 'POST'  
  }).done(function(response) {
   window.location.href = response.slug;
 }).fail(function(response) {
   $(this).append(response);
});
});
```

and here is my view

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>
            {{ $error }}
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

so anybody help me solve that! thank you

Comment: the `$(this)` might be a different object in the `fail` callback. try saving `$(this)` to a variable outside the callbacks, then use that variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - setting up `self` variable that stores reference to `$(this)`:

```js
$('#petition-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        formData = new FormData(self[0]);
    formData.append('content', tinymce.get('content').getContent());
    $.ajax({
        url: self.attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        method: 'POST'
    }).done(function(response) {
        window.location.href = response.slug;
    }).fail(function(response) {
        self.append(response);
    });
});
```

You can then remove `$errors` reference from your view, and I would probably `prepend` validation messages rather than `append` to make sure they are displaying above the form, but that's just the matter of preference.

Comment: it still not working. maybe i must to use parseJSON??